# How to get the first possible date(a) after a given date(b), where date(a) is not in a specific table and is not Sunday?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having trouble thinking through this problem. 
The exact wording of the problem is (EDIT)... Forgot the first half:

> Only Income_o and Outcome_o tables are considered. It is known that no money operations are being performed on Sunday.
>   For each date of reception of money on each of points, determine the date of money collection by the following rules:
>   1. Collection date equals to the date of reception (income), if there is no entry in the table Outcome_o for the money delivery on this date at this point.
>   2. Otherwise it is the first possible date after the date of reception, which is not Sunday and there is not any entry in the table Outcome_o for the delivery of money on this date at this point.
>   Output: point, date of reception, money collection date.
>
> The entries are unique by point and date.

1. Outcome_o(point, date, out)
2. Income_o(point, date, out)

So, I thought I would make a case statement that would select the date+1 if date in the outcome_o table, but then I realized I would have to do that a million times because there might be a long stretch of entries that are all in the outcome_o table.

So then I tried to make a temp date table from the min(Date) of outcome_o to the max(date)+2  of outcome_o and then take out the days that are sunday, and the days that are in outcome_o, but that gave me an error (something about maximum recursion reached limit 100).

I hope I was clear in this explanation, if not, let me know!

HERE is a picture of the correct output.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 1 [date]
  from income_o
 where [date] > '20170301'
   and [date] <= dateadd(day, 7, '20170301')
   and datepart(weekday, [date]) <> 0
   and not exists(select *
                    from outcome_o
                   where outcome_o.point  = income_o.point
                     and outcome_o.[date] = income_o.[date])
 order by [date];
```

given that Monday is weekday no 1 on your system.

Comment: Good  first try I think the question is not worded clealy .
I am working on it.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit confusing. Thanks Dani.

Answer (score 0):

I modified my answer to include your answer. I believe this includes the restrictions/rules you specified.

```
 select I.point, I.[date] O.date 
      from income_o I
      JOIN outcome_o O ON I.point = O.point
            WHERE O.[date] >= I.[date]          
            and O.date = (select top O2.[date] from outcome_o O2
                        where O2.point = I.point  
                        and  datepart(dw, O2.[date]) <> 1
                       )
    order by I.point, I.[date];
```

Comment: "... and there is not any entry in the table Outcome_o for the delivery of money on this date at this point ..." - you missed the date, no? :)

Comment: Yes, just needed to modify my where clause

Comment: sorry, I needed to edit my answer a couple of times. should be fine now.
Thank you @IngoB.

Comment: Never mind! :) But "date not exists()" will not work.

Comment: yes, that is also correct I thought of that when I was adding my answer and writing my sql code straight into SO, without using editor. Rookie mistake!. I think I have it all sorted out now.
Thanks for your editing @Ingo

Comment: Hey guys. I tried this query out and it returned nothing. I have added some additional information to my initial question  that may help with the confusion. Thanks!